# java hibernate persist a member hashmap <user-defined type, enum>

Tags: java, hibernate

n00b Java/hibernate question.  I want to persist my class DataStoreProvider using Hibernate defined like so -

```
class DataStoreProvider{
  @ElementCollection
  @MapKeyClass(value = NativeType.class)
  protected ConcurrentHashMap<NativeType, ODBCType> nativeToODBC;
  protected String name;

  //getters and setters
}
```

Referenced user defined classes are defined like so -

```
final public class NativeType {

  private String name;
  private int maxPrecision;
  private byte maxScale;

  public NativeType(String name, int maxPrecision, byte maxScale){
    this.name = name;
    this.maxPrecision = maxPrecision;
    this.maxScale = maxScale;
  }
  // getters and setters
}

public enum ODBCType {
  SQL_CHAR(1000000, 0),
  SQL_VARCHAR(1000000, 0),
  SQL_LONGVARCHAR(1000000, 0),
  SQL_WCHAR(1000000, 0),
  ;

  private final int maxPrecision;
  private final int maxScale;

  private ODBCType(int maxPrecision, int maxScale){
    this.maxPrecision = maxPrecision;
    this.maxScale = maxScale;
  }
  // getters and setters

}
```

NativeType technically only has an identity in the context of a DataStoreProvider. So I could include provider as an attribute of NativeType if needed, to make this clearer. And of course, the relationship NativeType-DataStoreProvider is also Many-to-One.

**How do I do this so that I have one table for DataStoreProvider, and another where DataStoreProvider's Id is listed against - NativeType columns, and ODBCType enum value?**

These are the Database Tables -

```
DataStoreProvider
===============
1|d1
2|d2

nativeToODBC
===============
1|@NativeType(VARCHAR2,4000,0)|ODBCType.SQL_VARCHAR
1|@NativeType(CHAR,4000,0)|ODBCType.SQL_CHAR
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am guessing I can use attribute converter to deal with the enum arguments - but I am overwhelmed and cant really think much

Comment: Nobody?? :( I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: I *think* you're looking for a Hibernate UserType, but it's still a bit unclear what you want to do. Could you post example tables for what you want?

Comment: Thanks @chrylis. Updated the post with some more details. Does this clarify what I am looking to achieve?

Comment: How exactly do you want to store that native type information? A string? A composite sequence of columns with a composite primary key?

Comment: I think a string works as long as I can preserve the properties of NativeType

Comment: Have you considered making it an `@Embeddable`?

Comment: I have it @Embeddable now - not sure how I address the annotations in the DataStoreProvider hashmap, and also how will the NativeType show in the table?

Comment: Did you just try and see what schema Hibernate generates?

Comment: I don't know how to get Hibernate to generate a schema. I have been using annotations